# How to prevent php timeout

Tags: c#, php, timeout

I'm currently having a timeout error with my massiv data import.
The php script takes about 90 minutes to complete but after exactly 60 minutes it returns error 500.
I'm calling the php script from a c# program like this:

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://path/to/my/script");
    request.Timeout = 7200000;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    ...
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    ...
}
```

I already tried some things, but none of them solved the problem:

- set "max_execution_time" to 7200 in php.ini
- set "session.gc_maxlifetime" to 7200 in php.ini
- call set_time_limit(0); at the start of the php function

Comment: Run it from the CLI and there are none of these limits. Does someone have to site there and watch the screen for 90 minutes the way you are running it now?

Comment: I'm surprised it works for an hour. Most web servers will cut off the response after 5 minutes. Long running scripts really ought to be called on the command line to prevent timeouts

Comment: @RiggsFolly and aynber: Sorry that I have to ask but what would be the difference if I call the php script from CLI? Wouldn't I get the same error than from my c# console app?

Answer (score 1):

Try using both `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in php.ini`.

`max_input_time` is used to handle GET or POST inputs, maybe this is what stops your script too soon.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
Sadly this didn't fix the problem :(